# Which OIDs to specify to functions like PQexecParams for array types?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

E.g., I want to pass a value like the following as a parameter to it:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, NULL, {4, 5, 6}}
```

Which OID should I specify for it and where can I find any related specs?

I tried using `2277` (`anyarray`) and `20` (`int8`), but it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it easily in the pg_catalog.pg_type table by looking up the int8 type which has as you already know oid 20. Then in the column typarray you will find the oid for the corresponding array type which happens to be 1016.